# MySQLi query error while running

Tags: php, mysqli

When I proceed to run the following query:

```
$sql3 = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO berichten (from, naar, file) VALUES ('.$id.', '.$to.', "'.$url.'")') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I'll received this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, naar, file) VALUES (2, 2, "b9173a1b9ade8767280009f9638bd987.caf")' at line 1
```

id = an id number,

to = an id number and

url = the filename (e.g. sound.caf)

Why do I get this error and what to do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding quotes around the `id` and `to` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` is a special SQL keyword. You have to escape it by putting it into backticks:

```
$sql3 = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO berichten (`from`, naar, file) VALUES ('.$id.', '.$to.', "'.$url.'")') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Besides that you might need to quote `ID` and `file` as you did for `$url`.

Btw. You should really consider to use prepared statements in order to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: [And here's a link to all reserved keywords in 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)